# how to return a json result in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to return a json result with the result format of

```
{
     "code": "0158"
}
```

but I end up with the value

```
[
    "0158"
]
```

am not sure what am doing wrong, I have tried two approaches and each give me the same value.

Option 1
I used a controller and a service here is my implementation
The controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "/eareport/spotchecksteams")
    public ResponseEntity<List> getSpotChecksteams(@RequestParam("country") String country,
                                                @RequestParam("projectId") String projectId){
        List<SpotCheckModel> report = dashboardService.getSpotChecksteams(country,projectId);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(report);
    }
```

the service class

```
 public List<SpotCheckModel> getSpotChecksteams(String country, String projectId){

        TypedQuery<SpotCheckModel> query = (TypedQuery<SpotCheckModel>) entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT e.code FROM SpotCheckModel e WHERE e.country = :country AND e.project = :projectId");
        query.setParameter("country", country);
        query.setParameter("projectId", projectId);
        return query.getResultList();

    }
```

option 2 I used a controller and a repository
my controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "/eareport/spotchecksteams")
    public Iterable<SpotCheckModel> getSpotChecksteams(@RequestParam("country") Optional<String> country,
                                                       @RequestParam("projectId") Optional<String> projectId){

        if(country.isPresent() && projectId.isPresent())
            return spotChecksRepository.findEntriesByUserId(country.get(), projectId.get());
        else
            return null;

    }
```

my repository

```
public interface SpotChecksRepository extends CrudRepository<SpotCheckModel, String> {

    @Query("SELECT e.eacode FROM SpotCheckModel e WHERE e.country = ?1 AND e.project = ?2")
    public Iterable<SpotCheckModel> findEntriesByUserId(@Param("country") String country, @Param("projectId") String projectId);

}
```

my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SPOT_CHECK")
public class SpotCheckModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="Country")
    private String country;
    @Column(name="Project")
    private String project;
    @Column(name="HtmlContent")
    private String htmlcontent;
    @Column(name="FileName")
    private String filename;
    @Column(name="Code")
    private String code;
    @Column(name="CreateDate")
    private DateTime createdate;
    @Column(name="UpdateDate")
    private DateTime updatedate;
```

Comment: `@Query("SELECT e.eacode FROM SpotCheckModel e WHERE e.country = ?1 AND e.project = ?2")` This doesn't select a `SpotCheckModel`, it selects a `String` (unless Spring Boot has got a lot more magic since last time I used it). I suspect the only reason you're not getting a ClassCastException is because of type erasure. Try inspecting the `report` variable in a debugger, or adding `SpotCheckModel model = report.get(0)`. I expect you'll find it's actually a list of strings.

Comment: Your controllers return a `List` and an `Iterable` both of those will be mapped to a JSON array, the square brackets `[]`

Comment: Hi @DCTID when i change to a `String` I still get the same result

Comment: @arriff you need to check if your correctly producing the string response, it seems you are returning an array everytime.

Comment: You have to return a single `SpotCheckModel` I assume you want all the fields of that and you only included `code` as an example. But, any fields you don't want returned, if any you can annotate with `@JsonIgnore`. Or better yet make a response object with the fields you want, map `SpotCheckModel` to that and return it so you don't expose anything in your DB that shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your controller as follows to get the desired output.Instead of returning the List, you need to return the custom object.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/eareport/spotchecksteams")
    public ResponseEntity<SpotCheckModel> getSpotChecksteams(@RequestParam("country") String country,
                                                @RequestParam("projectId") String projectId){
        SpotCheckModel report = dashboardService.getSpotChecksteams(country,projectId);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(report);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Vaibs it gives me an error `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to.SpotCheckModel`

Comment: Exactly which line you are getting that error? If you are getting list and you want to return list to end user then you need to change the return type of controllers method

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code

```
@GetMapping(path = "/eareport/spotchecksteams")
public ResponseEntity<?> getSpotChecksteams(@RequestParam("country") String country,
                                                    @RequestParam("projectId") String projectId){

List<SpotCheckModel> report = dashboardService.getSpotChecksteams(country,projectId);
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
try {
        jObj.put("code", report);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(jObj.toString());
}
```

Result:

```
{
   "code": "0158"
}
```